# Blocking interaction with 3D game objects by UI game objects

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface, game-development, unity-ui, unity3d-gui

I have some 3D objects, if I click on them then something happens. I implemented this using Physics ray casting like this

```
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            RaycastHit hit;
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
            {
               // Do something
            }
```

Now I have some UI panels (screenoverlay) which has buttons,  if any clickable 3D object is under the panel and I click on a button or on the UI panel, the 3D model also receives the click. . I don't want that. I want the UI to block interaction with any 3D objects it overlays.

Currently I am achieving this by checking if cursor is over a ui or not whith this,

```
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && CanClickOnObject && !UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject())
        {

            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            RaycastHit hit;
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
            {
```

This does the work done but I am not sure if this is the best way to do so. Is there any proper  or better way?

Answer (score 2):

Define

> proper or better way

[`EventSystem.IsPointerOverGameObject`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/EventSystems.EventSystem.IsPointerOverGameObject.html) returns `true` for **any** `GameObject` that is reacting to the `EventSystem`.

Depending on your setup this might include 3D objects that are implementing any of the `EventSystem` interfaces - most commonly the [`IPointerXYHandler`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IPointerEnterHandler.html) interfaces - using a [`PhysicsRaycaster`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/EventSystems.PhysicsRaycaster.html) on the `Camera`. So this might include more objects than pure UI elements.

In that case you might not come around to additionally execute a UI raycast ([`EventSystem.RaycastAll`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/EventSystems.EventSystem.RaycastAll.html)) and check for a specific UI layer.

As long as that is not the case for your project the way you are using might be good enough

Answer (score -2):

If you have a raycast that triggers on mouse click it will always trigger no matter where you click or what you have opened (UI included).

So you need to prevent the raycast with some condition and in your case, I don't think there's a better way to do that.

Comment: You are not giving much information beyond what OP has already provided. If you're unsure of a better way, then at lease provide some options. e.g. disabling the component doing the raycast or one of its parents.

Comment: @Zbajnek I'm sorry I upset you, I don't want to discourage. I provided my first comment during my review queue duties where I have 40 answers to triage. Only higher rep users have triage duty and it's and important part of maintaining stackoverflows readability and quality. Users on triage duty can't provide a meaningful answer that's tested for all the questions/answers they see during triage. I offered the feedback in hopes that you could improve as a contributor, gain rep and become a greater force for the community <3 I have some time today if you want me to test a solution.

Comment: Yes you did upset me and you know what upset me more? That my comments which were objective and I was trying to tell you my point were deleted.. I really thought that stack overflow is open for everyone but now here's the censorship :)) Why your comments weren't deleted? I wasn't hateful, I didn't write any slurs so I don't understand why it got deleted? That's wonderful! Again - yes you did upset me and this censorship reassured me that people with 1k+ reputation has the monopoly here. :)

Comment: I did not delete your comments, but I also didn't get the impression that they were objective or aimed to increase the value of the answer. In my last message I asked if you'd like me to provide a tested solution. Today you have not edited your answer or asked me to contribute one. Stackoverflow is only concerned with quality answers to software questions and this is exactly what makes it such a great resource. Where you see 'monopoly' I see users following the rules of stackoverflow to maintain a community moderated resource for engineers to quickly find the answers they need.

Comment: Last thing I will add to this: I will not follow some 'standards' from someone who didn't contributed to the question in any way and who's telling me that there's only the 'right way' of answering questions. It's your decision to down or up-vote it and I didn't break rules in any way. Cheers.

Comment: @Zbanjek I marked your answer as 'needing edits from author' and left a comment contributing to your answer with feedback on how to improve your response given the -2 your answer had. I didn't downvote your answer. I'm just trying to help you out so you can write more helpful answers.

Comment: @Zajnek I found the section of the Code of Conduct that pertains to your outrage. 
https://stackoverflow.com/conduct "Commenting
Comments are generally used in order to request clarification, leave constructive criticism, or to add relevant but minor or transient information to a post. They're largely regarded as potentially temporary and liberally deleted when no longer needed. Read more on the purpose of comments and their guidelines."